# Formato imagen Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

les agradeceré si me pueden orientar con un formato mas adecuado para la siguiente estructura :

```
<mat-card>
  <mat-card-content>
    <section class="columns" *ngFor="let r of registro">
      <div class="columns" >
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h1 class="mat-display-1">Nombre:</h1>
        <h1 class="mat-display-1">Raza:</h1>
        <h1 class="mat-display-1">Edad:</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h1 class="mat-display-1">Tor</h1>
        <h1 class="mat-display-1">Akita</h1>
        <h1 class="mat-display-1">20</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="columns" >
        <img mat-card-image src="https://material.angular.io/assets/img/examples/shiba2.jpg">
      </div>
    </section>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
La idea es lograr la siguiente:

1. Ordenar y agregar estilo al texto del centro: Label + valor
2. Forzar a que las imagenes del costado tengan siempre el mismo tamaño(son variables los tamaños)

Cualquier idea o apoyo se agradece!!!!